# References for local conservation law in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, conservation-laws, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Near the end of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor you can find a local conservation law for the densitized energy-momentum tensor contracted with a Killing vector. Does anyone have in mind any references that prove/indicate/comment that statement?

Comment: This is discussed in my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/175367/2451) and references therein.

Comment: Yes I have seen that! I just need a reference for my thesis' Literature. Any books, articles, papers, graffities or whatever else in mind?