# Conservation of Electromagnetic Energy-Momentum Tensor in GR

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

- In the follow Planck units have been used.
- The [Electromagnetic Energy-Momentum Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is $T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left[ F^{\mu \alpha}F^\nu{}_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{4} g^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\alpha\beta}\right]$ where $F^{\mu \nu}$ denotes the Faraday Tensor.
- From the second Bianchi identity we know that the 4-divergence of the Einstein Tensor $G^{\mu \nu}$ is null, i.e. $\nabla_{\mu} G^{\mu \nu}=0$.
- Putting this in the Einstein Equations $G^{\mu \nu}=8\pi T^{\mu \nu}$ we also have the conservation of the energy-momentum tensor: $\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu \nu}=0$.
- Now, the problem is that for the Electromagnetic Energy-Momentum Tensor the 4-divergence is not null, but we have instead $\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu \nu}=F^{\mu \nu}j_{\nu}$, with $j^{\nu}$ the 4-current.
- So is it not compatible with the Einstein Equations?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you read Dirac's 75 page booklet on GR and electrodynamics?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439753/2451

Comment: @DanielC nope, what's the specific name of that book? I can't find it

Comment: The great answer by professore Moretti can be supplemented by reading the relevant paragraphs of Dirac's book. I won't give you the amazon link (Jeff Bezos has enough money already), but he LoC one. https://lccn.loc.gov/75008690

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As soon as you have a non-zero current $J$, the EM field is not isolated and it is not the complete source of the gravitational field. On the right-hand side of the Einstein equations you should insert the whole stress-energy tensor and not only the EM one. With the added part you find a consistent system of equations.

Comment: Oh, then what is the complete stress-energy tensor?

Comment: It depends on what is the type of matter interacting with the EM field. The simplest model is a gas of non interacting charged particles...In this case, the complete stress-energy tensor is the sum of the EM one and the gas one (no added interacting term arises in this case).

Comment: $T^{ab}=T_{EM}^{ab}+ \mu V^aV^b$ and where $J^a=\rho V^a$ with $\rho = g \mu$ for some constant $g$.