# Noether's theorems and General covariance

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, lie-algebra, noethers-theorem, diffeomorphism-invariance

Given the action
$$ A = \int_{M} d^{4}x \ \mathcal{L}(\phi, \nabla \phi) $$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is a lagrangian density, or if you prefer $\mathcal{L} = \sqrt{-g} \mathcal{\tilde{L}}$ and $\mathcal{\tilde{L}}$ a function of spacetime.

From Noether second theorem we know that *diffeomorphism invariance* produces the following identity:

$$ \nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu \nu } = \nabla_{\mu} \bigg( \frac{2}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\delta \mathcal L}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} \bigg) = 0$$

Where we have an infinite dimensional Lie Algebra $ \big( \ \Gamma (M) \ , \ [ , ] \ \big)$ where $\Gamma ( M ) $ are the smooth sections of the Tangent bundle $TM$.
So, smooth vector field generates the lie group of diffeomorphism, hence *diffeomorphism invariance* is arena for the Second Noether Theorem.

In principle I know that if we have a family $\xi_{(i)}^{\mu}$ of killing vector fields($\mathscr{L}_{\xi_{(i)}^{\mu}} g_{ab} = 0$), we can construct from $T^{\mu \nu}$ a conserved current and a corresponging conserved quantity integrating the current over a Cauchy Hypersurface.

This I know. But my question is: If in principle we start from a *diffeomorphism invariant* action, what stops me from defining arbitrary $\xi_{(i)}^{\mu}$ such that with the usual Lie Bracket $[ , ]$ form a *finite dimensional* Lie subalgebra of $ \big( \ \Gamma (M) \ , \ [ , ] \ \big)$. The action would still be invariant w.r.t. the action of the Lie Group generated by this Lie Subalgebra, hence I can apply Noether **First** Theorem obtaining free a conserved current and an integral conserved charge. All this **without** the assumption that $\mathscr{L}_{\xi_{(i)}^{\mu}} g_{ab} = 0$.

I mean Invariance from an infinite dimensional Lie Algebra implies invariance from a finite dimensional Lie Subalgebra (es. $SO(3)$). So why we need a priori killing vector field *in this picture*? Where Killing vector field enters the picture if my construction doesn't need them and is arbitrary on the choise of the Lie Subalgebra generators?

Answer (score 1):

1. OP is considering the matter action $S_m\equiv A$ and its corresponding symmetric [SEM tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) $T^{\mu\nu}$ of matter.
2. Notice that the gravitational Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action $S_{EH}$ is not included. For a good reason: The [SEM pseudo-tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor) $t^{\mu\nu}$ to the gravitational field is marred with problems.
3. If one reads the fineprint of [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), one will notice that
   its conservation laws are only satisfied modulo terms proportional to $\delta S_m / \delta g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\delta S_m /\delta\phi$. The latter vanishes on-shell since it is the EOM for $\phi$, but the former does not since the gravitational sector is incomplete. Hence its conservation laws are violated.
4. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175186/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: I read your post 4. and I have great esteem for you, so I appreciate your answer, nevertheless I wanted to know more. From point 5. of your linked post we have $ d_{\mu}\Theta^{\mu}{}_{\lambda}~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~-\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}g_{\mu\nu,\lambda} =  T^{\mu\nu}\frac{\sqrt{|g|}}{2}g_{\mu\nu,\lambda} $. If I understand it correctly $d_{\mu}\Theta^{\mu}{}_{\lambda} =\partial_{\mu}\Theta^{\mu}{}_{\lambda}$, hence we have a trivial identity. (If we add the gravitational action what would have changed?).

Comment: Second, in your post 4. I don't see how esplicitly the lie sub algebra generators plays a role and where we arrive to the Killing condition by Noether first. I mean explicitly I didn't find a reference to see the details of this doubt, and a priori it seems to me that the two procedure should be the same, just specializing the second to a finite dim. lie subalgebra