# Symmetry of the Gravitational Stress Energy pseudo tensor

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Recently, I have been reading on the Gravitational [Stress-Energy pseudo tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor). It says in Wikipedia that one of the conditions for a suitable GSE pseudo tensor is that it has to be symmetric about the indices.

$$U_{\mu\nu} = U_{\nu\mu}$$

Why should this be the case?

Comment: As I recall, if it is not symmetric angular momentum would not be conserved. However I don't have the details to hand so I'm unwilling to risk a full answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie: The [relevant wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor) does invoke angular momentum conservation as the argument, but omits details.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68564/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I see. I'll do some more deeper research.