# What is the physical significance of the vector field term $X_{\nu}$ in the improved Noether current $T^{\mu\nu}X_{\nu}$?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, vector-fields, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

In Pedro Lauridsen Ribeiro's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256496) to deriving the improved stress-energy tensor using the improved Noether current, the variational equation for the improved stress-energy tensor is given by:
\begin{equation}
2\frac{\delta L(\phi,g)}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}\nabla_\mu X_\nu+\nabla_\mu(T^{\mu\nu}X_\nu)=\left(2\frac{\delta L(\phi,g)}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}+T^{\mu\nu}\right)\nabla_\mu X_\nu+X_\nu\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0.\
\end{equation}
Here $X$ is an arbitrary vector field $X$ on $M$ (i.e. an infinitesimal diffeomorphism).

In the above example, where the covariant derivative is defined with the levi-civita connection and the stress tensor is conserved, $X_{\nu}$ and its derivative act trivially and do not have physical significance. We see that $X_{\nu}$ is contracted with the conserved divergence of the stress tensor in the last term. In a hypothetical world, if the stress tensor was not conserved what would the physical meaning of $X_{\nu}$ be?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I understand most of the cases, we do not really know whether the $T^{\mu\nu}$ is actually symmetric or not, but, it should be conserved covariantly because improvement terms are in general, covariantly conserved. But they can alter the symmetry property of the stress energy tensor.

Comment: I am not asking about $T^{\mu\nu}$, I am asking about $X_{\nu}$. To get intuition of $X_{\nu}$, I am asking what its physical significance would be if it were not arbitrary and not independently defined from its derivative. This would happen in a made up world where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is not conserved and/or using a different connection.