# How to symmetrize the canonical stress-energy tensor?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, quantum-spin, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given the Lagrangian density for a real scalar field $\mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi)$, we obtain from Noether's theorem the canonical stress-energy tensor
$$ T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \partial_\nu \phi - g^{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L} $$
Can anyone tell me, or provide a (hopefully detailed) reference, why there is always (I think?) a rank $3$ tensor $X^{\lambda \mu \nu}$ such that $$\widetilde{T}^{\mu \nu} = T^{\mu \nu} + \partial_{\lambda} X^{\lambda \mu \nu}$$ is symmetric? I'm fine with assuming $g$ is the Minkowski metric, but I can only find this done in particular cases of $\mathcal{L}$ and no general argument.

Comment: See Wikipedia: [Belinfante–Rosenfeld stress–energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante–Rosenfeld_stress–energy_tensor)

Comment: Here is the important part of that article: “The curious combination of spin-current components required to make $T_B^{\mu\nu}$ symmetric and yet still conserved seems totally ad hoc, but it was shown by both Rosenfeld and Belinfante that the modified tensor is precisely the symmetric Hilbert energy-momentum tensor that acts as the source of gravity in general relativity.”

Comment: For a reference, I know this is discussed in the relevant section of Di Francesco et al.'s conformal field theory book, though only briefly.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119838/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68564/2451 and links therein.

Comment: For those interested in a complete reference, see the article 'Stress-Energy-Momentum Tensors and the Belinfante-Rosenfeld Formula' Gotay, M. J. and J. E., Marsden Contemp. Math., (1992) 132, 367-392